# Segmentation Fault -- Unable to write contents of one file to another

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fopen

I can't copy the contents of one file to another in C because there is a segmentation fault occurring and I don't know the cause.

I know it has something to do with the syntax of fgets or the way I am giving the size of the buffer.

```
char* argument = argv[2];
char buffer[argc + 1];

FILE *fp;
FILE *quiz_log;

fp = fopen(argument, "r+");
quiz_log = fopen("quiz.log", "a");

fgets(buffer, 80, fp);
memcpy("quiz.log", buffer, 80);

fclose(quiz_log);
fclose(fp);
```

Expected: Successful write to file "quiz.log"

Actual: Segmentation Fault: 11

Comment: Why are you using `argc+1` as the size of your buffer? That's just the number of command arguments, not the length of data. It's probably something small like 2 or 3. But then you're reading up to 80 characters into the buffer with `fgets(buffer, 80, fp)`.

Comment: `memcpy("quiz.log", buffer, 80);` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: There's no need to use `fgets()` to copy files, you don't need to read line by line. Use `fread()`.

Comment: You're never writing the buffer to a file. That's not what `memcpy()` does.

Comment: I'm trying to get the size of the file and allocate a buffer that has size one byte larger than the file

Comment: What does `argc` have to do with the size of the file? It's the number of arguments.

Comment: And even if that were the size of the file, `fgets()` just reads one line, not the whole file.

Comment: Step 0 should be error checking the `fopen` results. But there are many other issues already noted. You aren't going to learn C programming by trial and error. Looking up how to debug small programs will be an invaluable skill for you to learn!

Answer (score 3):

`argc` has nothing to do with the size of the file, it's the number of command line arguments. So there's no reason to use it as the size of the buffer.

Rather than try to read the file all at once, use a fixed-size buffer and read the file in a loop. Use `fread()` rather than `fgets()`, since that just reads one line.

You need to use `fwrite()` to write to the output file, not `memcpy()`.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
char* argument = argv[2];
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

FILE *fp;
FILE *quiz_log;

fp = fopen(argument, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open input file\n");
    exit(1);
}
quiz_log = fopen("quiz.log", "a");
if (quiz_log == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open quiz.log\n");
    exit(1);
}
size_t n;
while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, n, quiz_log);
}

fclose(quiz_log);
fclose(fp);
```